# Get HTML Image URL from Slideshow in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, image, slideshow

I'm using bootstrap carousel slideshow, and it's dynamically created from code behind. I want to add a button (Delete) to delete the current displayed image in the slide show.

The problem is that when I want to access the Html Image Source (Src) from the SlideShow, it will not accessed(It's empty).

My code looks like this:
Default.aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDeleteImage" />
    </triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="text-right">
        <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteImage" runat="server" Text="X" OnClick="btnDeleteImage_Click"/>
        </div>
        -
        -
        -  

       <!-- Div for Slide images -->       
        <div class="carousel-inner" id="sliderDiv" runat="server">   </div>

        -
        -
        -
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The html controls are dynamically added to the div as shown below:

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void CreateSlider(string imgUrl)
{  
    sliderDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<div class='item'>"));
    sliderDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<img alt='image'  id='imgSlide' src='" + imgUrl + "'>"));
    sliderDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"</div>"));   
}
```

Finnally, ButtonDelete code:

```
protected void btnDeleteImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlImage htmlImage = (HtmlImage)sliderDiv.FindControl("imgSlide");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", "<script>alert('" + htmlImage.Src.ToString() + "');</script>", false);
    DeleteImagesFromTemp(htmlImage.Src.ToString());
}
```

[image]

By the way, I also added the postback code in the page Load event.

Any suggestions?